# Python/Django ModelViewSet API with routers Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a geolocation API with Python and Django.
I already have a ModelViewSet API endpoint to display Providers at the URL http://localhost:8000/Providers and the Provider's details at http://localhost:8000/Providers/{id}.
I need to add another ModeViewSet to the endpoint /Providers/{id} so that I have an API endpoint /Providers/{id}/Polygons to display all polygons created by the provider with that id.
Therefore visiting the URL http://localhost:8000/Providers/{id}/Polygons should display all polygons created by Provider with that id and subsequently the details of that polygon.
How can I better create the url routers or the API ModelViewSet.
Thanks in advance.
The code I have keeps telling me this.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/providers/1/polygons
    ....
    ^ ^providers/<int:pk>/polygons/$ [name='polygons-list']
    ^ ^providers/<int:pk>/polygons\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='polygons-list']
    ^ ^providers/<int:pk>/polygons/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='polygons-detail']
    ^ ^providers/<int:pk>/polygons/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='polygons-detail']
    ^ ^$ [name='api-root']
    ^ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']

The current path, providers/1/polygons, didn't match any of these.
```

The details of the code.

Here's the Urls.py:

```
from .apiviews import ProviderViewSet, ServiceAreaViewSet, CreatePolygon, UserCreate, LoginView
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('providers', ProviderViewSet, base_name='providers')
router.register(r'providers/<int:pk>/polygons', ServiceAreaViewSet, base_name='polygons')

urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", LoginView.as_view(), name="login"), # Login
    path(r'swagger-docs/', schema_view),
    path(r'docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Polls API'))
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Here's the Serializers.py:

```
from .models import Polygon, ServiceArea, Provider

class PolygonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Polygon
        fields = '__all__'

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    polygons = PolygonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceArea
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here's the apiviews.py:

```
from .models import Polygon, ServiceArea, Provider
from .serializers import ProviderSerializer, ServiceSerializer

class ProviderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Provider.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProviderSerializer
    ...
    
class ServiceAreaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ServiceArea.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    ...
```

Here's the models.py:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    ...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ServiceArea(models.Model):
    ...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DefaultRouter** will use [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#re-path) for defining the urls, so you can not use angle bracket syntax for capturing the provider id, you can register it like this:

```
router.register(r'providers/(?P<provider_pk>[^/.]+)/polygons', ServiceAreaViewSet, base_name='polygons')
```